# Reverse engineering in pairs - is it possible?

Tags: ida, binary-analysis

I'm interested if anyone can share from his experience how to analyze complex binaries in pairs - 2 RE engineers. 
Are there any suitable methodologies, <del>tools</del> to help in such work?

**UPDATE**

This is indeed partly a duplicated question regarding tools, but not methodologies.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tools to work cooperatively on the same binary](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1347/tools-to-work-cooperatively-on-the-same-binary)

Comment: Methodologies are tools-specific.

Comment: Don't really agree with you, I think it's quiet the opposite.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know any concurrent solution that enables data exchange in realtime. But for IDA users there is [collabreate](http://www.idabook.com/collabreate/) which seems to allow to push/pull database changes.