# Generate a sig file from ELF executable

Tags: ida, firmware, mips

I have a mipsel executable (DvdPlayer from a RTD1283 firmware). I know that IDA is able to identify many functions. Then, I would like to generate a `.sig` file with signatures of these functions for use with other executable DVDPlayer (from other firmwares).

Would it be possible to convert the executable in a library ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [IDB_2_SIG](http://www.openrce.org/blog/browse/darko) plugin that generates signature files from the IDB itself.

One thing to note is that with gcc-built MIPS ELF files, many non-library symbols/function names (basically anything in a .o file) get entries in the dynamic symbol table and thus survive strip/sstrip as long as the binary is dynamically linked. So you *probably* won't need to generate signatures against this ELF in order to identify those same functions in similar ELF files from other DVDPlayer firmwares - they'll just be there and IDA will do its thing.

Comment: I'm using IDA 6.1 for windows on linux but I have no windows compiler. I searched for an IDB2Sig executable and found http://woodmann.com/collaborative/tools/index.php/Fast_IDB2Sig_and_LoadMap_IDA_plugins but no luck (bad .pat file).

I have DVDPlayer executables in both formats, static and dynamically linked. The idea was to generate a .sig file with the dynamically linked version of DvdPlayer and use it to identify the same functions in the static DvdPlayer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, either use IDA's FLAIR tools or use one of the tools mentioned here: [Tools to work cooperatively on the same binary](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1347/tools-to-work-cooperatively-on-the-same-binary/)

Comment: How? I can generate a .sig file from a library with: pelf library library.pat and sigmake library.pat library.sig, but if I try pelf with an executable then I get "non-relocatable elf module, skipped" message and .pat file is not created.

Comment: No, you can't generate a FLIRT signature out of a non relocatable ELF module as far as I remember.

Comment: In that case, follow the link I posted above instead.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my problem. I work with SEVERAL executable FILES and I want to use the information I get from one in the other. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I understood your question. Most of the tools to which I linked (such as https://crowdre.crowdstrike.com/) support that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, you cannot generate a FLIRT signature from a non relocatable ELF binary. You may have better luck using BinDiff to export the function names and comments. If this is all you need it should be enough, I use it a lot for this very same purpose.

Comment: Is it useful for files with many differences? I tried https://code.google.com/p/patchdiff2/ but only got results with similar files (dynamically linked with function names included in the executable).

Comment: BinDiff works with partially similar files. This is why this tool was wrote, I think.