# Is there an actively maintained collaboration plugin for IDA?

Tags: ida, disassembly, tools

There are many IDA Pro plugins that assist with collaboration, but are any actively maintained and known to work with the latest version of IDA (version 6.9)?

These are the tools that I'm aware of, and none of them are actively maintained.

- CrowdRE - Originally http://crowd.re or http://crowdre.crowdstrike.com. Now seems dead.
- [Ida Toolbag](https://github.com/aaronportnoy/toolbag) - Last commit two years ago (Jan 2015)
- [IDASynergy](https://github.com/CubicaLabs/IDASynergy) - Last commit two years ago (Jan 2015)
- [CollabREate](https://sourceforge.net/projects/collabreate/) - Last meaningful commit 2012
- [BinCrowd](https://github.com/zynamics/bincrowd-plugin-ida) - Last commit 2012
- [IDASync](https://github.com/nihilus/ida-sync-plugin) - Last commit 2012

Comment: solIDArity is "coming soon" for about half a year now, but it's probably somewhat relevant: https://solidarity.re/

Comment: There is also [Binary Ninja](https://binary.ninja/purchase.html) which promise collaboration for their Enterprise version.

Comment: The latest I know of is [FIRST](http://first-plugin.us). Can be run with an offline server, mostly useful for recognition of "seen-before" functions, won't annotate anything [below function labels](http://first-plugin-ida.readthedocs.io/en/latest/adding.html#data-collected-and-sent-to-first).

Answer (score 5):

At #SSTIC 2017, a french security conference, we will reveal a new solution :

https://www.sstic.org/2017/presentation/YaCo/

Last commit (in our private repo as of now...) was 5 minutes ago :-)

The YaCo plugin will be released along with its sources by the time of the talk.

Comment: If you are one of the authors, please state so clearly. I whish you the best of luck with this plugin.

Comment: YaCo has been released : the sources are available here :
https://github.com/DGA-MI-SSI/YaCo

Comment: Last commit on 15 Nov 2018

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/18495/18563), [IDArling](https://github.com/IDArlingTeam/IDArling) was released recently and is still being actively maintained (last commit was just over a week ago). Notably, it also won the [2018 IDA Plugin Contest](https://www.hex-rays.com/contests/2018/index.shtml#idarling).

**EDIT July 2021**
From the IDArling README:

> This project is no longer under active development and the more featured and up-to-date [fork](https://github.com/fidgetingbits/IDArling) is probably something more interesting for new comers. Also, IDA has announced an official support for collaborative reverse engineering session and one could also wait for this.

**EDIT June 2022**

[IDA Teams is now in beta](https://www.hex-rays.com/ida-teams/).